# Can I export tab, summarize() table from Stata to LaTeX?

Tags: latex, stata, summarize, tabulate

I was wondering if there is a way to export `tab, summarize()` table to LaTeX.

I have tried `eststo col: estpost tab` and `tabout` but error shows `option summarize() not allowed`.

Comment: Check out the help-file of the user-contributed command `tabout`, which can be installed by typing `ssc install tabout`. It can be used with LaTeX.